# How do I get the URI and Query String into the error.log using Apache2?

Tags: apache, error-log

I'm trying to get the URI and query string into the error.log so as to see what URIs are causing the errors, I have the following rewrite rule which is causing some problem trying to achieve this.  The `E=Q:$1` doesn't seem to be working.

So far the error log only gives me `/index.php` from the Request_URI or `%{xuri}e` variable.

Here is a snippet of the .conf file:

```
    <Directory /var/www/app/webroot>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico$
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,E=Q:$1]
    </Directory>

    SetEnvIf Request_URI "(^.*$)" xuri=$1
    SetEnvIf QUERY_STRING "(^.*$)" xquery=$1
    ErrorLogFormat "[%t] [%l] %7F: %E: [client\ %a] [%{Q}e] %{xuri}e %{xquery}e %M% ,\ referer\ %{Referer}i"
```

How do I have to change the ErrorLogFormat to get URIs as well as query strings (for each request that runs into an error) into my error.log?

Comment: I think this is *okay* as is, but could be greatly improved by being more explict: "Using this configuration, when I access index.php and [ force an error ] the error log becomes populated with [ literal copy/paste of error log ] "

Comment: I really don't know why the question was put on hold. The question was actually pretty obvious in my opinion. I edited it so it gets a little clearer...

Comment: Actually I like that question. Syntax-wise it should work. Interestingly enough it doesn't. You can use `%L --> Log ID of the request` in `ErrorLogFormat` and use this ID in the access.log to retrieve the corresponding entries (=same ID). Make sure that your access.log includes `%q --> The query string (prepended with a ? if a query string exists, otherwise an empty string).` and `%U --> The URL path requested, not including any query string.` then you are good to go :) ModSecurity is another alternative.

Comment: @HelloFishy Thanks for the edit and making it clear, I might just go with the %L Log ID, I was hoping to only to have to parse one log file.

Comment: You are welcome :)